# ListView with grid where padding causes child elements to shrink

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm currently styling a listview, in which I want to add a separating space between each entity in the `ListView`. For doing that, I use a `Grid` for each `ViewCell` with `Margin="0,0,0,10"`.

I can get my elements to fit inside the grid row, but if I add a padding to the row, to give it some top/bottom spacing, it just scales down the text inside the `grid.row`until eventually, it disappears.

```
<ListView Margin="10" HasUnevenRows="false" BackgroundColor="Fuchsia" x:Name="deviceList" ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" SeparatorVisibility="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="Silver" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center" RowSpacing="10">
                            <local:IconView Source="BLE.png" Foreground="#3b5998" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

How do I add padding to my `Grid.Row` without scaling down the child elements?

Comment: You can increase the Row Height. Also, Don't set the Rows and Column definitions for Auto

Comment: if i increase the row.height in the rowdefinition the items competely dissapear. (they move down, outside the row)

Comment: Can you attach a printscreen of your results, and what you want to achieve?

Comment: I think i fixed it. I used a horizontal oriented stackview instead and changed HasUnevenRows to True